# Cheaters detected

Tags: discussion, support

Two guys [MONIRUL ISLAM](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9456/monirul-islam) and [MD TOUFIQUL ISLAM](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/21268/md-toufiqul-islam) are cheating by promoting each other. Take a look at their questions and answers:

1. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67601/i-want-to-add-a-template-for-a-single-posts-of-different-categories-how-do-i-do
2. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67580/how-do-i-create-custom-post-type
3. [How reduce wordpress login session timeout time?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51874/how-reduce-wordpress-login-session-timeout-time) - here they deselect my answer, and select their answer as correct, but their answer is 100% copy/paste.
4. [How to Catch Last Widget box From Same Widget Area?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34141/how-to-catch-last-widget-box-from-same-widget-area)
5. [How to get user id which is done by buddypress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34583/how-to-get-user-id-which-is-done-by-buddypress)
6. [How to disable buddypress top mini adminbar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67587/how-to-disable-buddypress-top-mini-adminbar)

Comment: On it already. :) Stay tuned.

Comment: Next time just flag one of these posts and add an explanation to the flag message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The accounts had been temporarily suspended and given explanations that artificially inflating reputation (including stealing other's answers) and revenge downvoting are not acceptable behavior.